# Home page not opens on root folder (htdocs)

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

I create web site in joomla, multilanguage. And i write htaccess rewrite code for opens withouth index.php. Problem was my site not opens on root folder htdocs.

when i open site writin localhost

it rewrited to  this adress

localhost/tm/

site is empty, ony have symbol '>'

but when i move site to subfolder it opens

localhost/A/tm/

it opens,
when change language also opens. How can i editing .htaccess file to open site in root folder, help me...

my code here .htaccess ->

```
Options +FollowSymLinks


RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change Config.php
Enter the database name with connection name
Edit Server name, database name, id, password(if any)

Else, Change the Port otherthan 80/443

Comment: which config.php ? configuration.php? give me example code?

Comment: site working , there is no problem with db or server connection, only not working on root folder, but when i change language site working, i think problem is this code "RewriteRule (.*) index.php"